# React starter kit Hello World program error

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, react-starter-kit

I am trying to make an "Hello World" program as suggest on react tutorial.

But I created `helloworld.js` under `src` and `helloworld.html` in root. When I try to run my `helloworld.html` nothing happens (at all). And when I try to run `helloworld.js` error described below comes.

Is it some issue with babel?

[image: Error Screenshot]

[image: Html]

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the readme to properly set up?

Comment: I did whatever was instructed. I might have missed something but I don't know how to rectify this one.

Comment: what does your helloworld.html look like? the error in screenshot is expected, as you are trying to run JSX code that is supposed to be run in browser as if it's a pure JS node application

Comment: @lena I added screenshot of my html. If that error is expected then how am I supposed to run my program to see the output "Hello World"

Comment: When I am selecting "open in browser" from "view menu" for helloworld.html, then also nothing is happening.

Comment: You are using ES6 syntax but as far as I can tell have no transpiler to convert it to something viewable in a browser. The actual error you are getting sugguests you havent turned on es6 in the editor

Comment: ECMAscrip6 is ticked in library section. I have also set Java Script Language version to "JSX Harmony". I have read that " some browsers (Chrome, e.g.) will fail to load the file unless it's served via HTTP." Is it the case. If so how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question, why helloworld.html returns nothing at all:
You should not need to add src="src/helloworld.js" in the  tag. Otherwise the  will try to load your helloworld.js (which causes your second question). I have created a plunker - it works without the src="src/helloworld.js"

**html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <div>test</div>,
        document.getElementById('example')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Demo:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/ONtPtVkCsnEqNYYtDFAv?p=preview

For your second question. I guess you try to separate the script to a new file out from the helloworld.html. You do not need import because you add the react.js and react-dom.js in the html's head tag already. ReactDOM.render is already known when you load the src/helloworld.js from the script tag.

**html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="src/helloworld.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src/helloworld.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

**Demo:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/9uNkyaz65A4FMTHwdCtr?p=preview

**Edit:**
[image]

Click on the browser, for example, I clicked Chrome and got Hello World!:
[image]

Comment: file:///root/WebstormProjects/Tessact-React-Front/helloworld.html

Comment: I did exact thing you said. Gives File not found in chrome.

Comment: The fact that you are on file:/// makes me think you are not behind any web server. Are you using webstorm to open the html file?

Comment: Yes I am using Webstorm

Comment: I edited my answer, if you also click the chrome on the right hand panel in webstorm, do you have a page launched in chrome like I have got?

Comment: No. Page launches in chrome. But it says File not found.

Comment: I am using react starter kit. When I tried making an empty project like you did and putting helloworld.html in it, then it worked just like your's. How can I make it work with starter kit

Comment: Ok. I see now. With React Starter Kit, you do not add the html file and the js file in the way you did in your question. To solve your problem step by step, firstly,  have you run two commands "npm install" and "npm start" in your project folder ?

Comment: Where should I add them then?

Comment: You could  open a command prompt with admin right. Go to your react-starter-kit project folder, than you type "npm install".

Comment: I am still struggling with the setup. Running npm install give one or other errors like "babel-eslint requires a peer of eslint < "2.2.0, which is not insatalled". And when I install eslint < "2.2.0", eslint-config-airbnb has peer dependency on eslint 2.2.0. I really don't know what's wrong